# LyX | Color setting for this section

Tags: color, lyx, themes, interfaces

What's the color scheme setting for this section - what is it called? [image: Mentioned section]

I understand the syntax is \setcolor "" "" and that  accepts hex values - but what's the color name for this section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menu <kbd>Tools</kbd> → <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Look & Feel</kbd> → <kbd>Colors</kbd>  → <kbd>▒ bottom area</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! `<kbd>▒ bottom area</kbd>` was the one.